# How to make a window transparent in PyQt5 on Raspberry pi?

Tags: pyqt5, mdi

I've basically 2 questions.
I'm creating a PyQt5 application, where there's a mainwindow(), which I've created using mdi.
My subwindows are an analogclock and 15 subwindows each with 14 buttons. When button in a subwindow is pressed, it will open another subwindow and present subwindow should close. Each of 16 subwindows are written in their own class and I'm calling them from mainwindow class..

```
widget = analogclock()
widget1 = Example()
```

1) AnalogClock should be running permanently in the background on mainwindow, and other subwindows should be of transparent so that no matter which subwindow is opened, analogclock should be seen in the background.
    I've tried all the possible transparency instructions in the code but instead of getting transparency I'm getting a black background.. How can I make a subwindow transparent? 
I'm using Raspberry Pi module 3b on Linux OS.

2)I'm trying to close subwindow from other method of the same class.. Instructions I'm using is

```
class mainwindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(self)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.centralwidget.setLayout(QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget))

        self.mdiArea = QMdiArea(self.centralwidget)
        self.centralwidget.layout().addWidget(self.mdiArea)
        self.resize(500, 500)
        subWindow1 = QMdiSubWindow(self)

        widget1 = button.Example()

        subWindow1.setWidget(widget1)
        subWindow1.setFixedSize(310,255)

        subWindow1.move(100,100)
        subWindow1.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.mdiArea.addSubWindow(subWindow1)
        subWindow1.show()

    def c1(self):
        subwindow1.close()
```

This instruction is giving an error as subwindow1 is not defined, so I used

```
        mainwindow.__init__.subwindow1.close()
```

or

```
        mainwindow.__init__.widget1.close()
```

I'm getting an error as function has no attribute 'subwindow1' or 'widget1' respectively.

```
    def Tab1(self): #I'm calling this from a button in Example Class
        mainwindow.c1(self)
```

So ultimately I want to close the subwindow1 so that I can new subwindow2..

P.S: I didn't type the code as it was bit lengthy with 15 classes each with 14 buttons and a method for each button.

Thank you for your help..

These are some screenshots related to output..

2019-03-07-125048_1184x624_scrot.png

[image]

2019-03-07-125058_1184x624_scrot.png

[image]